# HTTP error 500 after migration

Tags: migrations

I was able to successfully take a back up of D7 site and then restore to target D7 site. When I visit the site, I get an error

> This page isn’t working. ...com is currently unable to handle this 
>   request. HTTP ERROR 500.

Added the code in settings.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare views_views_plugins() (previously
>   declared in
>   /home/.../public_html/sites/all/modules/views/includes/plugins.inc:15)
>   in
>   /home/.../public_html/sites/all/modules/hjhkjhj/views/includes/plugins.inc
>   on line 402

How can I fix the error to bring my site back up?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run YourDomain/update.php and [here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2013-04-01/fatal-error-cannot-redeclare-views_views_plugins) you can find why.

If the problem is not resolved and (hjhkjhj) is a custom module, then you can't have the same function with the name twice. In your case `views_views_plugins`.